# Список синонимов на С c помощью uthash.h

Tags: c, хеширование

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "uthash.h"

/* category library */
typedef struct
{
    int categoryid;
    char *categoryname;
    void *sinonyms;
    UT_hash_handle hh;
} twhitelistitem;

char * whlistbuf = NULL;
int whalloc = 0;
int whsize = 0;
twhitelistitem  *WHITELIST = NULL;
twhitelistitem  *WHITELISTTEMP = NULL;
twhitelistitem *twh;

static void load_whitelistrow( char * s)
{
    int newallocated = 0;
    int n = 0;
    char * ptr1;
    ptr1 = s;

    char * tok = strchr( ptr1, '|' );
    while( tok )
    {
        *tok = 0;
        if (n==0) {
              if (atoi(ptr1) == 0) {
                 return ;
              }
              if (whsize >= whalloc) {
                 newallocated = whsize + 64;
                 WHITELISTTEMP = (twhitelistitem *) realloc(WHITELIST, newallocated * sizeof (twhitelistitem));
                 if (WHITELISTTEMP == NULL) {
                    free(WHITELIST);
                    printf("Not enough memory for face whitelist\n");
                    return ;
                 }
                 memset((void*)WHITELISTTEMP + whalloc * sizeof (twhitelistitem), 0, (newallocated - whalloc) * sizeof (twhitelistitem));
                 whalloc = newallocated;
                 WHITELIST = WHITELISTTEMP;
              }
              WHITELIST[whsize].categoryid = atoi(ptr1);
        }                               
        if (n==1) {
               WHITELIST[whsize].categoryname = ptr1;
               twh = (twhitelistitem*)WHITELIST+(whsize * sizeof(twhitelistitem));
               printf("\n-- %s %d\n",twh->categoryname,twh->categoryid);
               HASH_ADD_KEYPTR(hh,WHITELIST,twh->categoryname,strlen(twh->categoryname),twh);
        }
        if (n > 1) {
              /* process synonyms */
        }
        ptr1 = tok + 1;        
        tok = strchr( ptr1, '|' );
        n++;
    }
    if (*ptr1) 
    {
        switch (n) {
               case 1:WHITELIST[whsize].categoryid = atoi(ptr1);break;
        }
    }
}

int i;
int main()
{
    /* process white list*/
    char* testbuf = "1|test|test1|test2\n2|two|second";whlistbuf = malloc(512);memset(whlistbuf,0,512); strcpy(whlistbuf, testbuf);
    char * line;
    char * whlistptr;

    if (whlistbuf == NULL) return ;
    whlistptr = whlistbuf;

    line = strchr( whlistptr, '\n' );
    while( line )
    {
        *line = 0;
        load_whitelistrow( whlistptr );
        whlistptr = line + 1;
        line = strchr( whlistptr, '\n' );
        whsize++;
    }
    if( *whlistptr )
    {
        load_whitelistrow( whlistptr );
        whsize++;
    }

    /* test */
    printf("loaded whitelist size: %d\n",whsize);
    for ( i = 0; i < whsize; ++i ) {
        printf("wh ID: %d\tname: %s\n",WHITELIST[i].categoryid,WHITELIST[i].categoryname);
    }
}
```

Вылетает на строчке HASH_ADD_KEYPTR(hh,WHITELIST,twh->categoryname,strlen(twh->categoryname),twh);
делаю вроде все также, как в доке по uthash - http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/userguide.html#_string_keys

Comment: @cromax, если откровенно, то я не знаком с этой библиотекой хэширования, но как-то странно выглядит `HASH_ADD_KEYPTR(...)` без предварительной инициализации самой хэш-таблицы.


Например в программах с CDSL hash_table явно прослеживается последовательность

    hash_table_init(&mytable, 10, NULL);
    ... потом заносим данные
    hash_table_insert(&mytable, &tmp->entry, str, len);
    .... работаем с ними
    if ((hentry =
      hash_table_lookup_key(&mytable, str, strlen(str))) == NULL) {
    ... запись не найдена

вызовов.

И еще, Вы уверены, что можно делать realloc этой таблицы?

Comment: делаю как тут - http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/userguide.html#_string_keys
только для нескольких элементов сразу.
мб неправильно делаю?
HASH_ADD_KEYPTR это макрос, я не очень знаком с ними, но приденный пример с документации работает нормально.
До 2го realloca не доходит даже, что равносильно вызову malloc;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, насколько я понял пример, там все не так.

--

В примере при первом вызове второй аргумент в макросе равен NULL, что очевидно означает, что таблица еще не инициализирована. Макрос создаст ее и поместит в этот указатель (у Вас WHITELIST) нужный адрес. И трогать его ни в коем случае нельзя.

--

Т.е. хэш-таблица - это и будет WHITELIST (точнее это будет адрес ее дескриптора). А аллокировать Вам нужно память, на которую указывает twh, содержащая hh (очевидно служебная структура для связывания синонимов).

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "uthash.h"

/* category library */
typedef struct
{
    int categoryid;
    char *categoryname;
    void *sinonyms;
    UT_hash_handle hh;
} twhitelistitem;

char * whlistbuf = NULL;
int whalloc = 0;
int whsize = 0;
twhitelistitem  *WHITELIST = NULL;
twhitelistitem  *twh = NULL;

static void load_whitelistrow( char * s)
{
    int newallocated = 0;
    int n = 0;
    char * ptr1;
    ptr1 = s; 
    int categoryid = 0;

    char * tok = strchr( ptr1, '|' );
    while( tok )
    {
        *tok = 0;
        if (n==0) {
              if (atoi(ptr1) == 0) {
                 return ;
              }
              categoryid = atoi(ptr1);
        }                               
        if (n==1) {
               twh = (twhitelistitem*)malloc(sizeof(twhitelistitem));
               memset(twh,0,sizeof(twhitelistitem));

               twh->categoryname = ptr1;
               twh->categoryid = categoryid;
               printf("\n-- %s %d\n",twh->categoryname,twh->categoryid);
               HASH_ADD_KEYPTR(hh,WHITELIST,twh->categoryname,strlen(twh->categoryname),twh);
        }
        if (n > 1) {
              /* process synonyms */
              printf("%s",ptr1);
        }
        ptr1 = tok + 1;        
        tok = strchr( ptr1, '|' );
        n++;
    }
    if (*ptr1) 
    {
        if (n > 1) {
              /* process synonyms */              
              printf("%s",ptr1);
        }
    }
}

int i;
int main()
{
    /* process white list*/
    char* testbuf = "1|test|test1|test2\n2|two|second";whlistbuf = malloc(512);memset(whlistbuf,0,512); strcpy(whlistbuf, testbuf);
    char * line;
    char * whlistptr;

    if (whlistbuf == NULL) return ;
    whlistptr = whlistbuf;

    line = strchr( whlistptr, '\n' );
    while( line )
    {
        *line = 0;
        load_whitelistrow( whlistptr );
        whlistptr = line + 1;
        line = strchr( whlistptr, '\n' );
        whsize++;
    }
    if( *whlistptr )
    {
        load_whitelistrow( whlistptr );
        whsize++;
    }
}
```

Вот верный пример. Убрал realloc, и убрал работу напрямую с WHITELIST;